# Sending base64 encoded PDF through Nodemailer using PDFkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, attachment, nodemailer, pdfkit

I have a function that returns me a base64 encode PDF, and I would like to send this as an attachement PDF file using nodemailer.

Regarding the nodemailer documentation, I found this example:

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: 'email1@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: 'email2@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Simulation', // Subject line
    html: '<p>SALUT</p>', // plain text body
    filename: 'file.pdf',
    attachments: [
          content: Buffer.from(
                'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD/' +
                    '//+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4U' +
                    'g9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
                'base64'
            ),

            cid: 'note@example.com' // should be as unique as possible
        },
```

However, this did not work for me. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it was all a formatting issue.

Here is how to use B64 on Nodemailer:

```
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'email1@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: 'email2@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: "Hey this is a subject example", //subject
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: `myfile.pdf`,
        content: 'THISISAB64STRING',
        encoding: 'base64',
      },
    ],
  };
```

then just send it the classic way.